# how dose nginx server_name works

Tags: nginx, nginx-config

I have two websites one is `server1.example.com` the other is `server2.example.com`. So I add two servers in `nginx_config`

```
server{
        listen  80;
        server_name server1.example.com;
        location / {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9090;
        }
    }

    server{
        listen  80;
        server_name server2.example.com;
        location / {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9091;
        }
    }
```

It works well

[image: server1]
[image: server2]

if I delete one of them , the result does not meet my expectations.
As I delete the conf of `server2.example.com`

```
    server{
        listen  80;
        server_name server1.example.com;
        location / {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9090;
        }
    }

    # server{
    #     listen  80;
    #     server_name server2.example.com;
    #     location / {
    #         proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9091;
    #     }
    # }
```

When I visit `server2` I think I will get `404` or `500` http code. But I get the response from `server1`

[image: server2]

why?

Answer (score 0):

The `server_name` gives way to use different virtual names and for nginx is to see which section servers.

If no section matches it then `nginx` will use the first declared server. Which in this case for you is `server1.example.com`. Or you can override that by using the `default_server` keyword.

```
server{
   listen  80 default_server;
   server_name server1.example.com;
   location / {
       proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9090;
   }
}
```

You should see the below url for more details

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html